# Finding Rotation matrices between two cameras for "Stereorectify"

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

So I have a depth map and the extrinsics and intrinsics of the camera.I want to get back the 3D points and the surface normals .I am using the function[ReprojectImageTo3D](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d).In the stereo rectify function to find Q how do I get the The rotation matrix 
 **between**
the 1st and the 2nd cameras’ coordinate systems? I have individual rotation matrix and translation vector but how do I get it for "between the cameras?"
.Also this would give me the 3D points .Is there a method to generate the surface normals?

Comment: were you able to figure it out? I have the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have the extrinsic matrix of both cameras, can't you simply take the inverse extrinsic matrix of camera 1, multiplied by the extrinsic matrix of camera 2?
Also, for a direct relation between the two cameras, take a look at the Fundamental Matrix (or, more specific, the Essential matrix). See if you can find a copy of the book Multiple View Geometry by Hartley and Zisserman.

As for the surface normals, you can compute those yourself by computing crossproducts on the corners of triangles. However, you then first need the reconstructed 3D point cloud.

Comment: Thanks and for the translation vector  between the cameras do I just take the difference ?

Comment: Well a true extrinsic matrix is build like this: [r_11 r_12 r_13 t_x; r_21 r_22 r_23 t_y; r_31 r_32 r_33 t_z; 0 0 0 1] where the last column is the translation of the origin. So translation from one camera to the other is then the difference between these two translation vectors.

Comment: I really dont have the extrinsic matrix of the cameras .I have the translation vector and rotation matrix for individual images( are extrinsics image dependent rather than being camera dependant?).So I use the difference for the translation vector and the inverse thingy u mentioned for rotation