# OpenCV: compute Rotation Matrix for stereoRectify

Tags: opencv, matrix, rotation

I want to compute the rotation and translation matrices to use for stereoRectify in open CV. The rectified images look twisted and totally incorrect (Like completely twisted cone at the center of the image going both directions)

I have the rotation and translation matrices of both cameras....

Also, this is a smilar post but it is not helping: [Finding Rotation matrices between two cameras for "Stereorectify"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055864/finding-rotation-matrices-between-two-cameras-for-stereorectify)

I am sharing my code below...

```
// Create interinsic parameters matrix given the translation and rotation matrecis
Mat CreateExternsicParamsMat(Mat R, Mat T)
{
    Mat ext1(4,4,T.type());
    Mat ext2(4,4,T.type());
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<3; j++)
            ext1.at<double>(i,j) = R.at<double>(i,j);
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
        ext1.at<double>(i,3) = T.at<double>(i,0);
    ext1.at<double>(3,3) = 1;
    ext1.at<double>(3,2) = 0;
    ext1.at<double>(3,1) = 0;
    ext1.at<double>(3,0) = 0;
    return ext1;
}


Mat ext1 = CreateExternsicParamsMat(R1,T1);
Mat ext2 = CreateExternsicParamsMat(R2,T2);
Mat ext1inv;
invert(ext1,ext1inv);
Mat ext = ext1inv*ext2;

for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<3; j++)
      R.at<double>(i,j) = ext.at<double>(i,j);

for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
    T.at<double>(i,0)=ext.at<double>(i,3);

stereoRectify( M1, D1, M2, D2, img_size, R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q);
```

Comment: Can you also post your left and right intrinsics and extrinsics please?